# MONEY Datatype CAST issue in IIF or CASE clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, sqldatatypes

Here is a sample query sample that produces correct output:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (
    keydate DATE,
    price   MONEY
);

INSERT INTO @T(keydate, price) VALUES
('2014-07-23', 32464),
('2014-07-26', 32478),
('2014-07-27', 32473)


;WITH
cte_tbl (keydate, price, prev_price1)
AS (
SELECT TOP(1) 
    T.keydate,
    T.price,
    T.price AS prev_price
    FROM @T AS T
    ORDER BY T.keydate
UNION ALL
SELECT
    T.keydate,
    T.price,
    T.prev_price
    FROM (
    SELECT
        TT.keydate,
        TT.price,
        IIF(ABS(TT.price - cte_tbl.prev_price1) < 10, cte_tbl.prev_price1, TT.price) AS prev_price,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TT.keydate) AS ROWNUM
        FROM @T AS TT
        INNER JOIN cte_tbl ON cte_tbl.keydate < TT.keydate
    ) AS T
    WHERE T.ROWNUM = 1
)

SELECT *
FROM cte_tbl 
ORDER BY keydate
```

The **correct** output is:

```
keydate price       prev_price1
2014-07-23  32464.00    32464.00
2014-07-26  32478.00    32478.00
2014-07-27  32473.00    32478.00
```

If I change to decimal prices holding MONEY with a dot:

```
INSERT INTO @T(keydate, price) VALUES
('2014-07-23', 324.64),
('2014-07-26', 324.78),
('2014-07-27', 324.73)
```

The output would be **wrong**:

```
keydate price   prev_price1
2014-07-23  324.64  324.64
2014-07-26  324.78  324.64
2014-07-27  324.73  324.64
```

Prices are in CTE statement actually but it does not reject the mess.

I need to store them as normal prices and have correct output behavior as above:

```
('2014-07-23', 324.64),
('2014-07-26', 324.78),
('2014-07-27', 324.73)
```

The output should be:

```
keydate price       prev_price1
2014-07-23  32464.00    324.64
2014-07-26  32478.00    324.78
2014-07-27  32473.00    324.78
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: was there a question in here somewhere?

Comment: You have `SELECT ...   T.price, T.price AS prev_price ...`. Why do you expect the 2 columns to show different results?

Comment: To elaborate on my snarky comment above... What are you trying to accomplish with your CTE?  What is about the first set of results that is **correct**, and why is your second set **incorrect**.  As it is right now, us as potential answerers have to infer your intent, rather than getting it explained to us.

Comment: It works correctly without dots in prices. I need dots because prices in MONEY datatype holding dots. With dots it works incorrectly. That's the question. CTE statement is ok. The problem is in IIF (or CASE). Could be CAST to DECIMAL operator or something...

Comment: So, the only problem is that when the table holds 324.64 in the price column, you want to output 32464.00 for the price, and 324.64 for prev_price?

Comment: That was my bad. I forgot to reduce all values by 100. There is no problem at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the diffence between `32464` and `32478' is more than 10, but the difference between`324.64`and`324.78` is not. Change this line:

```
IIF(ABS(TT.price - cte_tbl.prev_price1) < 10, cte_tbl.prev_price1, TT.price)
```

to:

```
IIF(ABS(TT.price - cte_tbl.prev_price1) < 0.10, cte_tbl.prev_price1, TT.price)
```

If you are reducing the prices by a factor of 10, you need to reduce the comparison by a factor of 10.

Comment: @GarethD I figured this was probably the issue, but I wasn't really understanding why one result set was correct and the other wasn't.  If his values are going to have any sort of range about them (like a factor of 10) then the code posted will continue to work for one set of values, and not another.

Comment: And this would produce the exact output in his "The output should be" code block?   Notice the difference in decimal usage between price and prev_price in that block.